# Remove WordPress Gutenberg button default styles

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Trying to build a site with WordPress + Gutenberg and Tailwind.

It's including a bunch of crappy inline styles in the  for every single button and I don't want to have to constantly fight to overwrite these with !important or a specificity battle.

Example...

```
<style id='global-styles-inline-css' type='text/css'>
...
...

a:where(:not(.wp-element-button)) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.wp-element-button, .wp-block-button__link {
                background-color: #32373c;
                border-width: 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-family: inherit;
                font-size: inherit;
                line-height: inherit;
                padding: calc(0.667em + 2px) calc(1.333em + 2px);
                text-decoration: none;
}
```

How do you stop Wordpress from injecting this junk into your theme?

Comment: What are the specific properties you don't want to include?

Comment: @Millhorn anything related to links or buttons, it making columns is I guess okay, but it making opinionated styles is never okay

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unwanted native styles with [wp_dequeue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/) function that you can insert in `functions.php` file like this:

```php
function remove_wp_block_library_css(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' ); // Remove WordPress core CSS
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library-theme' ); // Remove WordPress theme core CSS
    wp_dequeue_style( 'classic-theme-styles' ); // Remove global styles inline CSS
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style' ); // Remove WooCommerce block CSS
    wp_dequeue_style( 'global-styles' ); // Remove theme.json css
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_wp_block_library_css', 100 );
```

Note: Some lines are useless, depends of your WordPress version.